# How highlight text with spacing in UILabel?

Tags: swift, uilabel

How highlight text with spacing in UILabel? 
this is my UILabel [image]

But I need to make a selection like here: 
[image]

Comment: If you want to select the text, you will need a UITextView instead.

Comment: ok, but how select text with spacing like second screen?

Comment: and i select the text in my Label, but i dont set spacing in selected.

Comment: Try using `NSParagraphStyle`  with attributed string.